# Query to Get All IDs When Duplicate Data Has Different Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've got a SQL table similar to this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|   ID   | FirstName | LastName  | SomeOtherData|
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  200   | Robert    | Barone    | Foo          |
|  228   | Doug      | Heffernan | Bar          |
|  2091  | Robert    | Barone    | Foo          |
|  3921  | Doug      | Heffernan | Bar          |
|  291   | Greg      | Warner    | Barfoo       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Now what I'm having trouble producing is a table that'll list both IDs for a given Person, assuming that FirstName and LastName are used to indicate duplicates. So, basically I'm trying to get:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|   ID   | OtherID | FirstName | LastName  | SomeOtherData|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  200   | 2091    | Robert    | Barone    | Foo          |
|  228   | 3921    | Doug      | Heffernan | Bar          |
|  291   |         | Greg      | Warner    | Barfoo       |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Would anyone be able to help me out with something like this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like there's no unique indexes on First/Last, which means that potentially there can be more than 2 Ids for a person.  Are you sure you can only have 2 IDs?

Comment: How many other id's? Is that a "max 2 id's" or can there be plenty?

Comment: I know for sure there are at max 2 IDs, at least in my current situation. I verified with a query to count the duplicated instances for any given FirstName, LastName combo.

Comment: If it is only 2 it is trivial though possibly slow - make a query for first (possibly lowest or max id), then a subselect to get the other id or the OtherId field. Multiple is a lot harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which will transform the data from rows into columns:

```
select [1] Id,
  [2] OtherId,
  firstname, 
  lastname
from
(
  select id, firstname, lastname,
    row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname
                      order by id) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(id)
  for rn in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7ec6/6)

Or you could use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  max(case when rn = 1 then id end) Id,
  max(case when rn = 2 then id end) OtherId,
  firstname,
  lastname
from
(
  select id, firstname, lastname,
    row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname
                      order by id) rn
  from yourtable
) src
group by firstname, lastname
```

The above will work great if you have a known number of duplicate values (1, 2, etc). You could also implement dynamic SQL if you have more than 2 id's. The dynamic SQL would look like:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by id) as varchar(50))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(cast(row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by id) as varchar(50))) +' as Id_' + cast(row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by id) as varchar(50)) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colNames + ', firstname, lastname from 
             (
                select id, firstname, lastname,
                  row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname
                                    order by id) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(id)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7ec6/12)

The result of all 3 would be:

```
|  ID | OTHERID | FIRSTNAME |  LASTNAME |
-----------------------------------------
| 200 |    2091 |    Robert |    Barone |
| 228 |    3921 |      Doug | Heffernan |
| 291 |  (null) |      Greg |    Warner |
```

Comment: Wow - impressive query. I've never heard of using a PIVOT before.

Comment: The good thing here is that this also works with more than 2 doubles ;) One of the rarely used sql commands that many people do not know. Still very useful. Anyone who did not do OLAP will rarely know that.

Comment: @JToland pivoting data comes in very handy in these situations.

Comment: @bluefeet If I wanted to get ALL columns from the `yourtable`, rather than just the FirstName, LastName, and IDs, how would I need to modify the queries? I keep getting compile/syntax errors when I'm trying to add those in...Thanks again!

Comment: @JToland If you are using the `PIVOT`, then you would have to add them to the subquery first, then add the column to the other query. If you are using the `CASE` then you will have to add it to the `GROUP BY`.  However, if you want to add more fields, it could throw off the result of the query so you will have to modify the query slightly. See this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7ec6/13